# How much do I have to grow a plant before harvesting seeds?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-garden-flower-town

I just grew a plant in *Flower Town* with 5 people contributing to blooming it. How many more do I need to harvest seeds and do favorite colors/plants they are growing also come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the next time it is watered after blooming the plants will exchange pollen, creating seeds to be harvested. Each additional encounter will produce a seed until the plant has no more to produce.

Different plants bloom at different rates, so it can go from 3-5 watering to be partially to fully bloomed.